# How to make Keyboard Type Number Pad Restricted to be only English number in Xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode

I am working in very simple app in textfield. I make it Number Pad 
and I need NumberPad to be only English number the user cannot change to any language.

How to make Keyboard Type NumberPad restricted to be only English number in Xcode 9?

I am using Swift 4 in Xcode 9

[image]

Comment: 1) What do you mean by 'English number'? 2) Do you mean this in comparison to arabic numbers? If so: Why do you care what the user gets shown? What will arrive once you got `Int(textfield.text)` will be a just a number - no matter what the user was shown

Comment: If you want to know what kind of keyboard you can present: maybe take a look into the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardtype)

Comment: 1) What do you mean by 'English number'? 2) Do you mean this in comparison to arabic numbers?

Comment: Okay, I will give you a hint: number 11 is called `asciiCapableNumberPad` but it is iOS10+

Comment: thank you very much Micheal, it's work now

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for

```
textfield.keyboardType = .asciiCapableNumberPad
```

?